# Is there a way in Kotlin to access a particular member of an object (or class) using only the name of the object (or class)? Like a default member

Tags: class, object, kotlin, member

For example I would like to create a single `Matrix` object (3x3) that has an `Array<Array<Double>>` "default member":

```
object Matrix{
    val matrix: Array<Array<Double>> = Array(3) { Array(3) { 0.0 } }
}
```

And access that particular member from `main()` like this:

```
val M12: Double = Matrix[1][2]
```

Instead of writing `Matrix.matrix[1][2]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [operator overloading](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html) to access the element:

```
object Matrix {
    val matrix: Array<Array<Double>> = Array(3) { Array(3) { 0.0 } }
    operator fun get(i: Int) = matrix[i]
}
```

Alternately, you could also overload it as such:

```
object Matrix {
    val matrix: Array<Array<Double>> = Array(3) { Array(3) { 0.0 } }
    operator fun get(i: Int, j: Int) = matrix[i][j]
}
```

This allows access like `Matrix[i,j]`

Both of these can be used at the same time.